# Regenerating Session ID not helpful if cookie is physically copied/recreated

Tags: php, security, session, cookies, web

This could be a basic concept but I am bit confused over it.

Guidelines tell us to regenerate the session ID after user login in order to make it usable if it is being sniffed over the network thus preventing a replay attack.

My point is that even after the session ID is regenerated it would again be stored in a user browser and if an attacker or some other person who has access to the user's system he could copy that cookie and replay in another browser to gain post login access irrespective of TLS/NON TLS connections?

is it correct to say that this kind of activity can not be prevented?

Suggestions/Views please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, if you're being sniffed - you're being sniffed, and you can't do anything about that, except for encrypting the traffic.

ID regeneration *does* help mitigate replay attacks if done regularly (i.e. not just on login or privilege changes, but on regular time intervals), but traffic sniffing is just one way of hijacking sessions, not all of them.

A cookie may be *planted* into a victim's browser (aka session fixation), which is primarily what ID regeneration on login prevents.
A cookie may also be stolen/leaked via another vulnerability in the application.
A session ID may be deterministically guessed under some circumstances (timing side-channel attacks, insufficient randomness, or even plain brute force).

The goal of ID regeneration is to start a clean session, that an attacker cannot have hijacked already.

Comment: `A cookie may be planted into a victim's browser (aka session fixation), which is primarily what ID regeneration on login prevents.` session ID is stored in a cookie and if copied from there and replayed in another browser the login will still happen is that right?

Comment: Don't know what you mean, but ... You write the login info into the newly-generated session, which the attacker cannot have copied. Best practice is to also delete the old ID upon regeneration.

Comment: when session is created it stores the session ID in client's browser,this means the regenerated session will also store session ID on the client side browser cookie.Lets just say I inspect that cookie via firebug and create the same in another browser this will login me in another browser on basis of regenerated cookie?

Comment: If you steal the *regenerated* cookie - yes, of course it will log you in.

Comment: Actually I was asked how to prevent this from happening.